# Extracting parts of character string with gsub

Tags: r, string, gsub, extract

I am quite new to R and am working now with a script that was done by me and my supervisor.
Unfortunately I am unable to reuse one instance of gsub() for names of my samples.
The previous version looked like this (Anterior and Posterior varied throughout the df):

```
"1: Anterior LN_60_026.fcs"
```

and was taken apart using

```
cell.counts$EH_ID <- gsub("\\d+: (Anterior|Posterior) LN_(\\d{2})_\\d{3}.fcs", "LM02\\2", cell.counts$Sample)
cell.counts$Position <- gsub("\\d+: (Anterior|Posterior) LN_(\\d{2})_\\d{3}.fcs", "\\1", cell.counts$Sample)
```

Now I am faced with a similar problem which requires some minor adjustment. Because I don't know how gsub() syntax works I am stuck with:

```
"1: mLN_681_030.fcs"
```

for which mLN and spleen vary throughout the df and the code that I tried to adapt doesn't work anymore:

```
cells$Mouse_ID <- gsub("\\d+: (mLN|spleen)(_\\d{2})_\\d{3}_\\.fcs", "AA_0\\2", cells$Sample)
cells$tissue <- gsub("\\d+: (mLN|spleen)_(\\d{3})_\\d{3}.fcs", "\\1", cells$Sample)
```

I should add that the "tissue" separation works, it's sample number extraction that doesn't.
If anyone could explain to me what I am doing wrong and what the characters in this code do specifically, I'd be very grateful. 
P.S.: Yes I have used ?gsub but I find the help files in R quite beginner unfriendly and didn't understand much.

Comment: gsub uses regular expressions. This site (https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great reference. And this one (https://regexr.com/) has a great tool for interactively testing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting exactly 2 digits in the second capture group in your mouse ID line and you have a trailing underscore before your filename.

Also in the second regex you have not escaped the `.` which still works because an un-escaped `.` will match any character but should be `\\.` as below.

```
# > str <- "1: mLN_681_030.fcs"
# > gsub(str, pattern="\\d+: (mLN|spleen)(_\\d{3})_\\d{3}\\.fcs", replacement = "AA_0\\2")
# [1] "AA_0_681"
# > gsub(str, pattern = "\\d+: (mLN|spleen)_(\\d{3})_\\d{3}\\.fcs", replacement = "\\1")
# [1] "mLN"
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked and looks almost as it should. But how do you get rid of the "_" after "0"? I should have specified that the outcome should be "AA_XXXX"

Comment: moving the underscore out of the capture group `"\\d+: (mLN|spleen)(_\\d{3})_\\d{3}\\.fcs"` -> `"\\d+: (mLN|spleen)_(\\d{3})_\\d{3}\\.fcs"` the `()` define what is captured by the regex and become accessible in the numbered outputs in this case `"\\2"`